# Setting the same min/max for multiple raster layers QGIS

Tags: qgis, dem

I have 268 hgt-files from [Viewfinder Panorama](http://www.viewfinderpanoramas.org/Coverage%20map%20viewfinderpanoramas_org3.htm) that I'm using to create an elevation model, but each of the files has its own `min` and `max`-value in `Layer Properties - Symbology - Band Rendering`.

Currently it looks like this:

[image: Screenshot from QGIS]

I found I can set the min and max of each layer manually, to get an uniform scale, but this is a hassle for all 268 layers. So I was wondering if I'm missing an option somewhere, or if im doing something completely crazy?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could build a virtual raster. Go to Raster - Miscellaneous - Build virtual raster, select all rasters as input, uncheck "Place each input file in a separate band":

[image]

Then change symbology of the virtual raster.

Comment: Aha. I was aware of the virtual raster, but I figured I had to fix this first