# Color different of two Sentinel 2A (L1C) images from the same sensing date

Tags: sentinel-2, pixel, histogram, image-classification

i'm new to this GIS Q&A websites and remote sensing as well, so sorry for this too basic question. It's about my Sentinel 2 (Level-1C) images. I downloaded 2 images with the same sensing date (09-09-2018). One is next to the other, meaning the first image is just one *path* away (like in Landsat) from the second one. However, some portion of the first image overlaps the second one.

I made a natural color composite out of it and thought that the color would be perfectly the same. But turns out, they're slightly different. I need to know what seems to be the cause of this color different. Is it just the visualization (histogram) or it goes back to the spectral value? Since i'm willing to do pixel based image classification to these image, this matter would be so significant to the result.

Additional information:

1. no correction (geometric and radiometric) has been applied to the images
2. it's not even a mosaic image, they're two different natural color raster i simply visualize in qgis

[image: Color different in landscape level]

[image: Color different in pixel level]

Comment: Try creating a virtual raster to see if it is only the visual appearance that differ: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/296155/setting-the-same-min-max-for-multiple-raster-layers-qgis/296160#296160

Comment: It looks to me like they are stretched differently; for each image, right click on the name in the layer menu, choose "Properties" and under "Style" check the red, green and blue band min and max values for each image are the same. If you just set them all to "Min 0" and "Max 2000" you should get a reasonable output.